# Custom Nodes: can't animate CollectionProperty items

Tags: python, animation, node-editor

When I try to animate a property that is stored in a CollectionProperty attached to a custom node (by hovering it and pressing `I`), I get the following error message:

```
Failed to resolve path to property, try manually specifying this using a Keying Set instead
```

[image]

Here's my custom node definition:

```
class ColorRampItem(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    offset = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name='Offset', default=0.0, min=0, max=1)
    value = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(name='', min=0, soft_max=1, subtype='COLOR')


class MyCustomNode(Node, MyCustomTreeNode):
    '''A custom node'''
    bl_idname = 'CustomNodeType'
    bl_label = 'Custom Node'

    items = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=ColorRampItem)

    def init(self, context):
        # Add two test items
        item_0 = self.items.add()
        item_0.offset = 0
        item_0.value = (0, 0, 0)

        item_1 = self.items.add()
        item_1.offset = 1
        item_1.value = (1, 1, 1)

    def draw_buttons(self, context, layout):
        for item in self.items:
            split = layout.split(align=True, percentage=0.7)
            split.prop(item, 'offset', slider=True)
            split.prop(item, 'value')
```

Is this an error on my side, or is it a limitation of the custom nodes system?

[Here is a Blender scene with the full working code.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7f012s8zoyyepj1/animate_props_test.blend?dl=1)
To reproduce, press "Run Script", switch the node editor type to the custom node tree and add the custom node, then try to press `I` while hovering one of the controls of the node.